# PL/SQL Check Digit, luhn using MOD 11

Tags: oracle, plsql, luhn

**So here is the question:
Write code to take in an id and determine if the check digit is correct**

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
    Set SERVEROUTPUT ON
 DECLARE
      val_num NUMBER := '&user_input';
      holder NUMBER := 0;
      y NUMBER := 0;
      conv_string VARCHAR2(20);
   BEGIN
     conv_string := to_char(val_num*10);
     for x in 1..length(conv_string) loop
       y := to_number(substr(conv_string, -x, 1));
       if mod(x,2) = 0 then
         y := y * 2;
        if y > 9 then
         y := y - 9;
        end if;
       end if;
      holder := holder + y;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line ('Check is '||(11-Mod(holder, 11)));
 END luhn;
   /
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

**The return is:**

```
SQL> @ loop
Enter value for user_input: 036532
old   2:       val_num NUMBER := '&user_input';
new   2:       val_num NUMBER := '036532';
Check is 2
```

**It should be 6**

Comment: In a normal check digit routine, after that loop you need to take the `MOD` of `holder`, and subtract it from something.  Exactly what you MOD and subtract depends on the algorithm.

Comment: it is the luhn algorithm

Comment: @WW. code is updated

Answer (score 3):

Before actual execution

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

to enable SQL*Plus to fetch database output buffer.

Here is solution: https://community.oracle.com/thread/837639?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: 770100020011360 should check as 6 but it is checking as 24

Comment: Then your implementation has some flaw. Describe the algorithm for calculating the check digit

Comment: -Assign weights to each digit of the id #. The weights in MOD11 are from 2 through a maximum of 10 beginning with the low order position in the field.
-Each digit in the id # is multiplied by its weight
-The results of the multiplication are added together
-This product is divided by the modulus number 11
-The remainder is subtracted from the modulus number 11 giving the -check digit

Comment: @JeffMercier You should update the question with your description of the check digit algorithm.  How do you expect anyone to tell you if your code is wrong if you don't tell them what the algorithm is?

Comment: @Husqvik its luhn algorithm

Comment: The link provided by husqvik has the answer in it, 2 things need updating in your implimentation  1) the first line after the begin needs to be 'conv_string := to_char(val_num*10)'  and 2) the dbms_output needs to be 'dbms_output.put_line('Check is ' || to_char(10-Mod(holder, 10)));'

Comment: I saw the link but it's in a function not a straight up plsql that's why it was throwing me off, you can't do a return in my code since it is not a function.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson with your code that was implemented it is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different variations of the luhn algorithm, so looking at these implementations and your (I think incomplete) description in the comments I think this may be fairly close to what you are looking for, and gives the correct checksum for 036532 as per your initial question.

Hope it is helpfull

```
Set SERVEROUTPUT ON
 DECLARE
      val_num number := '036532';
      holder NUMBER := 0;
      y NUMBER := 0;
      conv_string VARCHAR2(20);
   BEGIN
     conv_string := to_char(val_num);
     FOR X IN 1..LENGTH(CONV_STRING) LOOP
       Y := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(CONV_STRING, -X, 1));
       IF ((X+1) > 10) THEN 
          Y := Y * 10;
       ELSE
          Y := Y * (X + 1);
       END IF;
       IF (Y >= 10) THEN 
          HOLDER := HOLDER + TO_NUMBER(substr(TO_CHAR(Y), 1, 1)) +  TO_NUMBER(substr(TO_CHAR(Y), 2, 1));
       ELSE
          HOLDER := HOLDER + Y;
       END IF;
     END LOOP;

         HOLDER :=  MOD(HOLDER, 11);
         Holder := 11 - mod(holder, 11);
     dbms_output.put_line ('Check is '|| holder);
 END luhn;
   /
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```