# Need Luhn Modulus 16 coding example to generate a check digit in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, luhn

Does anyone have a working function available to use within Oracle using PL/SQL which implements the Luhn Mod 16 Algorithm to generate a check digit for an input code number such as the following example?  `0B012722900021AC35B2`

LOGIC

1. Map from HEX into Decimal equivalent `0 B 0 1 2 7 2 2 9 0 0 0 2 1 A C 3 5 B 2`  - becomes  `0 11 0 1 2 7 2 2 9 0 0 0 2 1 10 12 3 5 11 2`
2. Start with the last character in the string and move left doubling every other number - 
   Becomes `0 22 0 2 2 14 2 4 9 0 0 0 2 2 10 24 3 10 11 4`
3. Convert the "double" to a Base 16 (Hexadecimal) format. If the conversion results in numeric output, retain the value. 
   Becomes: `0 16 0 2 2 E 2 4 9 0 0 0 2 2 10 18 3 A 11 4`
4. Reduce by splitting down any resultant values over a single digit in length. 
   Becomes `0 (1+6) 0 2 2 E 2 4 9 0 0 0 2 2 10 (1+8) 3 A 11 4`
5. Sum all digits. Apply *the last numeric value* returned from the previous sequence of calculations (if the current value is A-F substitute the numeric value from step 1)
   Becomes `0 7 0 2 2 7 2 4 9 0 0 0 2 2 10 9 3 5 11 4`
6. The sum of al l digits is 79 `(0+7+0+2+2+7+2+4+9+0+0+0+2+2+10+9+3+5+11+4)`
7. Calculate the value needed to obtain the next multiple of 16, in this case the next multiple 16 is 80 therefore the value is 1
8. The associated check character is `1`

Thanks Lee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PL/SQL Check Digit, luhn using MOD 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170104/pl-sql-check-digit-luhn-using-mod-11)

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate due to the hexadecimal piece.

Comment: I have revised the wording of `step 5)` from your comment on my answer. Please check my interpretation is correct.

Comment: @LeeReynolds - I put a lot of effort into trying to help you solve your problem but you have abandoned this thread before it reached closure. Poor show,

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);


DECLARE
    luhn VARCHAR2(100) := '0B012722900021AC35B2';

    digits VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE;
    DigitSum INTEGER;
BEGIN

    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(luhn, '.', 1, LEVEL)
    BULK COLLECT INTO digits
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(luhn, '.', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;  

    FOR i IN digits.FIRST..digits.LAST LOOP
        digits(i) := TO_NUMBER(digits(i), 'X'); -- Map from HEX into Decimal equivalent
        IF digits.COUNT MOD 2 = i MOD 2 THEN -- every second digit from left            
            digits(i) := 2 * TO_NUMBER(digits(i)); -- doubling number
            digits(i) := TO_CHAR(digits(i), 'fmXX'); -- Convert the "double" to a Base 16 (Hexadecimal) format
            IF (REGEXP_LIKE(digits(i), '^\d+$')) THEN
                -- Reduce by splitting down any resultant values over a single digit in length. 
                SELECT SUM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(digits(i), '\d', 1, LEVEL))
                INTO digits(i)
                FROM dual
                CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(digits(i), '\d', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
            END IF;    
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    FOR i IN digits.FIRST..digits.LAST LOOP
        -- I don't understand step 5), let's simulate it
        IF digits(i) = 'E' THEN digits(i) := 7; END IF;
        IF digits(i) = 'A' THEN digits(i) := 5; END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- The sum of all digits
    SELECT SUM(COLUMN_VALUE)
    INTO DigitSum
    FROM TABLE(digits);

    -- Calculate the value needed to obtain the next multiple of 16 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 16 - DigitSum MOD 16 );

END;
```

Comment: Do you know if i can add a document to this thread? This will show the steps much better than i can explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which implements the steps you outlined in your question:

```
create or replace function get_luhn_16_check_digit 
    ( p_str in varchar)
    return pls_integer 
is
    b16 sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll() ;
    n16 sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
    tot simple_integer := 0;
    chk_digit pls_integer;
begin
    -- step 1)
    select to_number(tkn, 'X')
    bulk collect into n16
    from ( select substr(p_str, level, 1) as tkn
                 from dual
                 connect by level <= length(p_str));
    b16.extend(n16.count());

    for idx in 1..n16.count() loop
        if mod(idx, 2) = 0
        then 
            -- step 2) and 3)
            b16(idx) := to_char( to_char(n16(idx)) * 2, 'fmXX');
            -- step 4)
            if length( b16(idx)) = 2 then
                 b16(idx) := to_number(substr(b16(idx),1,1)) + to_number(substr(b16(idx),2,1));
            end if;  
        else 
            b16(idx) := trim(to_char(n16(idx)));
        end if;
    end loop;

    -- step 5) and 6) 
    for idx in 1..b16.count() loop
        if  b16(idx) not in ('A','B','C','D','E','F') then
            tot := tot + to_number(b16(idx));
        else
            tot := tot + n16(idx);
        end if;
    end loop;

    -- step 7) and 8)
    chk_digit := (ceil(tot/16)*16) - tot; 
    return chk_digit;
end;
/
```

To run:

```
select get_luhn_16_check_digit('0B012722900021AC35B2') from dual;
```

This now returns `1`.  Here is [a LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f26k0wo5kwa89zduns6h1rczg).

---

There is still the question of what happens when the modulus 16 is greater than 9; for instance, this value returns `15`.

```
select get_luhn_16_check_digit('22111111111111111111') from dual;
```

A decimal result such as `15` is obviously not a check **digit**, which suggests you need an additional step 9). Perhaps we need to convert `15` -> `(1+5)` -> `6`. Or Perhaps the digit should be base16? Please edit your question to confirm the appropriate rule.

Comment: thanks for the above. I will try and explain. The document i have states -

Comment: give me until the morning to try and explain what i mean in more detail

Comment: Sorry, i think I’ve left off the character mapping part.

The document states the following char mapping must be used.

Position  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
Character 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
Does this help?

Comment: From what i can work out from the document i believe the logic is, in the case of char#6 it starts off as 7, then it doubles to 14, 14 in the char mapping becomes E, because E can't be used as it's not numeric the original value of 7 is used in the calculation. That's the same for char#18

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate it. That's worked for a number of inputs I've tried. I'll look at the two digit check string problem.

Comment: i can't seem to fix the two check digit issue. Is there a way of contacting you outside of this forum to discuss a resolution. I'm happy to pay you for your time. Thanks

Comment: @LeeReynolds - to start with the " two check digit issue" is a business logic issue: what  is the rule for resolving it? If you can specify the rule the fix would be very straightforward. As for hiring me, yes, it's possible, as I am a freelancer. However, there are complications with my current placement; it seems unlikely that this task would justify the paperwork .

Comment: I don't normally vent against anonymous drive-by downvotes but this one is most provoking. I have invested a lot of time in shaping this answer. So, whoever you are may you always have a stone in your shoe.